# SSRS Expression to Substitute 0 for NA

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I've the SSRS Expression that is provided below. The issue with that expression is that the last column sometimes shows `#VALUE!` when the 1st column value is `NA`. It is basically failing to calculate.
How can I fix this expression so that it shows the correct numeric value? One possible solution is to substitute `0` for `NA`, but how can I achieve this ?

**Expression:**

> =iif(Fields!NumType.Value = "1",iif(reportItems!txt_Current_Filing_Firm.value = "","0",reportItems!txt_Current_Filing_Firm.value),"1") - IIF(Fields!NumType.Value = "1",iif(reportitems!txt_Compare_Filing_Firm.value = "","0",reportitems!txt_Compare_Filing_Firm.value),"1")

**Current Output in SSRS:**

```
Column 1 | Column 2 |  Column 3

NA          3456.00    #VALUE!
NA        347856.00    #VALUE!
NA      98763456.00    #VALUE!
NA         33456.35    #VALUE!
```

**Expected Output in SSRS:**

```
Column 1 | Column 2 |  Column 3

0          3456.00    -3456.00
0        347856.00    -347856.00
0      98763456.00    -98763456.00
0         33456.35    -33456.35
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL statement and an example of the results of the statement. It might be easier to modify the SQL itself. Failing that, if I can see what the raw data from the dataset looks like then I should be able to hlpe.

Comment: Here is the SQL Statement - select DISTINCT Fr.FilingID, fq.AbbreviatedInstructions, fq.Mapping, fq.Number, fa.Grouping, fa.Instructions, fa.[Order], fa.DetailOrder, fa.GroupingOrder, fq.Id, null as Name, fa.FormatString, fa.[Type] as NumType, ISNULL(fa.OverrideAnswer,fa.SourceAnswer) as FinalAnswer from WorkBench.dbo.FilingAnswer fa
 join WorkBench.dbo.FilingQuestion fq
 on fa.FilingQuestionId = fq.id
 join WorkBench.dbo.FilingReview fr
 on fr.Id = fq.FilingReviewId
 where fr.FilingId in (@FilingID,@FilingID_Compare)
 and fr.FundId is null

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I'll look at this tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: I think I solved this problem. Thanks for your help. Check out the solution in my reply. - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Thought to share. We need to replace "NA" with 0. It works!

=iif(Fields!NumType.Value = "1",iif(reportItems!txt_Current_Filing_Firm.value = "" OR reportItems!txt_Current_Filing_Firm.value = "NA","0",reportItems!txt_Current_Filing_Firm.value),"1") - IIF(Fields!NumType.Value = "1",iif(reportItems!txt_Current_Filing_Firm.value = "" OR reportitems!txt_Compare_Filing_Firm.value = "NA","0",reportitems!txt_Compare_Filing_Firm.value),"1")

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. You might want to clean up your code by adding a function to the reports that converts your various inputs to comparable numeric values.

Comment: Then the expression would look something like this 

    = Code.CleanValues(Fields!col1.Value) - Code.CleanValues(Fields!col2.Value)

The function would be something like this...

    public function CleanValues (myValue) as decimal
     dim result as decimal
     Decimal.TryParse(myValue,result)
     return result
    End Function

Comment: Agreed. It's a good idea to write a function that will reply the calculated value. Much cleaner approach. That would be my next level of optimization of code. I really appreciate your help. Thanks again.